# Autocomplete jQuery UI only works the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm working on a hotel search engine form with the Autocomplete jQuery UI on Bootstrap, the problem is that the autocomplete only works the first time the page is load. When you change the page and go back, the autocomplete stops working and doesn't show anything.

Here are the php and js files i've used:

scripts.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#hotel-destination").autocomplete({

    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 3,
    source: "search_engine.php",

 });

});
```

search_engine.php

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {

    $hotelsSearchEngine->autocomplete($_GET['term']);

};
```

As you can see here, i call the autocomplete function that it's placed on another file called class.php. Here it is:

class.php

```
class db {

  protected $db;

  public function __construct() {

      $this->db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

      if ($this->db->connect_errno) {
        die('Error de conexión.');
      }

  }

  public function __destruct() {

    $this->db->close();

  }

 }

class hotelsSearchEngine extends db {

    function autocomplete($term) {

       $request = "SELECT zone_name, destination_name, country_name FROM hotel_destinations WHERE zone_name LIKE '".$term."%'";
       $result = mysqli_query($this->db, $request) or die();

       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

           if ($row['zone_name'] != $row['destination_name']) {

              $terms[] = utf8_encode($row['zone_name']).", ".utf8_encode($row['destination_name']).", ".utf8_encode($row['country_name']);

           }else{

              $terms[] = utf8_encode($row['zone_name']).", ".utf8_encode($row['country_name']);

           };

       }

       echo json_encode($terms);

    }
}
```

As i said before, this only works the first time the page is load, if you go to another page, and then return to the page where the autocomplete is, it doesn't show anything. Another thing that i've noticed, is that if i open it on a private tab on Chrome, it works again if i restart the browser.

Thank you.

Comment: Please describe any errors you find in the console. If you have FireFox, I would use FireBug so you can see the AJAX request and response easily. Also enable persistent logs to better capture the logs.

Comment: Testing here and unable to replicate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/dv4vchdy/